# ¿Como hago para saber cual dato de la instruccion de mi consulta no cumple el parametro WHERE?

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber de que forma puedo saber cual dato no se cumple a la hora de realizar mi consulta a la base de datos desde `PHP`.

Es decir quiero saber de que forma puedo condicionar mi código  para saber qué parámetro de la instrucción `WHERE` se esta incumpliendo.

Es para cuando alguien ingrese mal el dato dentro de un formulario se sepa si es porque no existe alguno de los parámetros ingresados.

```
<?php   
    $con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','freatico') or die ('Error en la conexion');    
    $sql="SELECT Nivel FROM medicion WHERE idp='$_POST[pun]'and Nivel>=1.20";    
    $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database');  
    //Valida que la consulta esté bien hecha  
    if( $resultado ){

     //Ahora valida que la consuta haya traido registros
    if( mysqli_num_rows( $resultado ) > 0){

    //Mientras mysqli_fetch_array traiga algo, lo agregamos a una variable temporal
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ) ){

      //Ahora $fila tiene la primera fila de la consulta, pongamos que tienes
      //un campo en tu DB llamado NOMBRE, así accederías
      echo $fila['Nivel'];
    }

    }
    else {
        echo 'NO EXISTE EL PUNTO/NO HAY PUNTOS CRITICOS';
    }

    //Recuerda liberar la memoria del resultado, 
    mysqli_free_result( $resultado );

    //Si ya no ocupas la conexión, cierrala
    mysqli_close( $con );

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: No es posible de forma directa, debes pensar en el `WHERE` como un todo. Lo unico que podrais hacer es en caso de que no traiga registros, realizar nuevas consultas cada consulta con cada uno de las condiciones del `WHERE` para determinar cual no tiene registros.

Comment: @Xerif JUMM.. comprendo amigo, pero masomenos de que forma lo harias tu. Me podrias dar un pequeño ejemplo para guiarme. Te agradezco!

Comment: Desconozco el contexto, pero yo seguramente le diria al usuario que su busqueda no arrojo resultados con los criterios indicados y en todo caso, hacer otra consulta en el `else` bien con un 'DISTINCT' o bien con `OR` en lugar del `and` y mostrarle esos resultados como sugerencia. Ahora mismo no dispongo de mucho tiempo, pero seguro que hay algun compañero que te pueda ayudar o en todo caso mañana quizas me anime a darte un ejemplo.

Comment: Bueno. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución mas simple es con varios `SELECT` :

```
$ipd = intval($_POST[pun]);
$NivelMinimo = 1.20;

$sql="
  SELECT 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Nivel) 
       FROM medicion 
        WHERE idp=".$idp." AND Nivel>=".$NivelMinimo."
    ) as NivelesIDValido,
    (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM medicion 
       WHERE idp=".$idp."
     ) AS cantidadIDsValidos,
    (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM medicion 
       WHERE Nivel>=".$NivelMinimo."
    ) AS cantidadNivelesValidos;
";
```

---

El `GROUP_CONCAT`nos devuelve una cadena que es una lista separada por comas. Así que tendremos que modificar el `while / echo`

```
if( $resultado ) {
  //Ahora valida que la consuta haya traido registros (la consulta va a traer siempre resultados pero no esta de mas comprobar)
  if( mysqli_num_rows( $resultado ) > 0){

  //Mientras mysqli_fetch_array traiga algo, lo agregamos a una variable temporal
  while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ) ){
    // Ahora $fila tiene la lista de Niveles+pid válidos, 
    // cuantos idp son válidos 
    // y cuantos Niveles son validos
    // var_dump($fila);
    if (!empty($fila['NivelesIDValido'])) { // si hay resultados
       echo 'PUNTOS CRITICOS: ' . $fila['NivelesIDValido']; 
    } else { // no hay resultados
      if ($fila['cantidadIDsValidos']==0) {
        echo 'NO EXISTE EL PUNTO ';
      }
      if ($fila['cantidadNivelesValidos']==0) {
         echo 'NO HAY PUNTOS CRITICOS ';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tabla ejemplo:

```
idp nivel
1   1.5
1   1.3
2   1.75
3   2
4   1.1
```

---

con `$idp = 1` y `$NivelMinimo = 1.20`

El resultado es

```
NivelesIDValido cantidadIDsValidos  cantidadNivelesValidos
1.50,1.30               2                   4

PUNTOS CRITICOS: 1.50,1.30
```

---

con `$idp = 1` y `$NivelMinimo = 4.20`

El resultado es

```
NivelesIDValido cantidadIDsValidos  cantidadNivelesValidos
(null)                   2                  0

NO HAY PUNTOS CRITICOS
```

---

con `$idp = 15` y `$NivelMinimo = 1.20`

El resultado es

```
NivelesIDValido cantidadIDsValidos  cantidadNivelesValidos
(null)              0                        4

NO EXISTE EL PUNTO
```

---

con `$idp = 15` y `$NivelMinimo = 4.20`

El resultado es

```
NivelesIDValido cantidadIDsValidos  cantidadNivelesValidos
(null)                 0                   0

NO EXISTE EL PUNTO NO HAY PUNTOS CRITICOS
```